# What does -= and += mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

This JavaScript code will result in -11, but I don't know what is the mathematical process.

```js
let x = 2;
let y = 4;
console.log(x -= y += 9)
```

Comment: I would reject any pull request that had code like that. While it is possible this could be concretely explained, the amount of time for someone to look at that code and understand what it is doing is prohibitive and there is likely a much better solution for arriving at the desired result.

Comment: This certainly feels like a homework/interview question that's the sort of code you will (hopefully) never actually run into.

Comment: 2 - (4 + 9) ...

Comment: This is a weird piece of code, but the evaluation process, I'm fairly sure, is `x -= (y += 9)`, which means 1. add 9 to y, so y = 13. Then 2. subtract y from x, so x -= 13 or x = x - 13 = 2- 13 = -11

Comment: Just because you can, does not mean you should

Comment: [Subtraction assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Subtraction_assignment), [Addition assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment)

Comment: An understanding of [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) would also aid your understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break down each step:

```
y += 9 
y = y + 9
y = 4 + 9
y = 13
```

```
x -= y
x = x - y
x = 2 - 13
x = -11
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be helpful to think of this as

```
let x = 2;
let y = 4;
let z = x -= (y += 9);
console.log(z);
```

We're setting the term in the parantheses to y += 9 (which is 13), then setting z to x -= 13, which is -11.

That being said, this is a horrible way of writing this!

Answer (score 0):

The execution start with y=y+9 which is 4+9=13 then it evaluates x=x-y  which is 2-13=-11
so answer is -11.